# Multi Farm and Peat Bog setup

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forestry

I'm using a 3x3 MultiFarm and it works for the most part I think. But I left it idle and it seems to have glitched or my understanding is not correct. When it initially placed the bog earth, it left blocks of water which confused me until I read that a block of water needs to be touching (diagonals count) every block of bog earth in order to produce peat bog. But when I came back to it, everything was bog earth and there was no water block. I observed it for a while and it still didn't create the blocks of water. I then destroyed some of the bog earth blocks and it finally placed some blocks of water. But it didn't cover all the blocks, is this normal/intended?

It seems to me the easiest thing to do is the "fence" up all the bog earth and just place water on top of it.

[image: Screenshot of the setup]

Other tidbits:

- I'm testing in a Creative mode
- I've adjust time if that's relevant
- I think I'm currently in swamp biome
- MineCraft 1.5.2 + Forestry 2.2.2.2

Comment: I think it's a bug in forestry where it doesn't keep the waterblocks (I've seen the same happen with tilled soil)

Comment: I see, were you able to come up with a workaround? I haven't gotten around to testing mine yet. Also, feel free to to post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I found a [forum post](http://www.mod-buildcraft.com/forums/topic/mutlifarm-bug/) regarding someone else having the same issue.

Comment: According to FTB wiki, placing water on top of it (or above) shouldn't work. http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Peat Did it?